# How to get On/Off FlipSwitch to trigger function

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

Hi i found these On/Off flipswitches https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/ that will generate CSS3 On/Off flipswitches with animated transitions.

Im using Google Apps Script / Add-on and i have the CSS + HTML on my client-side.
I would like it to trigger a function when it's switched, both on & off should trigger the same function.
[image]

Simple button:

[image]

This is how a **Simple Button** does it now:

**Client-Side:**

```
<button onclick="google.script.run.insertTextToCellA();" id="ButtonA">Button A</button>
```

And it triggers my **Server-Side** function:

```
function insertTextToCellA(){
var cellA = table.getRow(1).getCell(2).getChild(0);
    cellA.setText('Hello Testing!');         
  }
}
```

And this is how my code looks like with **Switch Button**:

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

**Question:** I don't have any 'onclick' with this switch button, how can i make it trigger my server-side function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind an onclick event to any HTML element.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" onclick="google.script.run.insertTextToCellA();" checked/>
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9L13du75/)